# Rules for minimum sample size required for prediction using two variables

Tags: prediction

For a binary prediction based on two variables, e.g., predicting responder using variables a1 and a2.  What are the rules that may be applied for sample size calculation?

Comment: With inference, sample size is calculated to achieve a desired power. When the goal is prediction, there is no inference, so power is not a consideration.

Comment: Agree with AdamO, you may consider event per variable method.

Comment: I don't see anything unclear in this question.